# How does AllCast app access the screen?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, screen

I'm trying to get the Android screen content. At this point, I don't really care if it is from Java or C/C++ with NDK, all that I want is to have a framerate higher than what "screen shots screencast " usually allow (around 5 fps tops).

I noticed the AllCast app which does exactly that, plus streams to various devices such as tvs or pcs. Most of all, it does not require root to do so. I would be ok to work with a root solution but this app is very intriguing.

The only workable solution I've found so far would be to tweak the `screenrecord` app from kit-kat which allows just that. However, this involves recompiling with android headers from full Android source, which may change from release to release and may change from vendor to vendor.

Edit :

Ok, it seems that [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) is a workable solution from API level 21 and up.
Level 17 introduced [DisplayManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/display/DisplayManager.html#createVirtualDisplay(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.view.Surface,%20int)) where you can also create a virtual display. Mirroring the main display to your virtual one seems to require root.
As a side note, it seems possible to add wireless displays with [Miracast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast) since that release (4.2). This was mentioned in the release notes.

Comment: Look at `createVirtualDisplay` method in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks promising. This seems to be from API level 21. Level 19 and below may leave /dev/graphics/fb0 framebuffer open for reading (I do not have such a device but the graphic framework was reworked for level 19). This leaves a gap betweeen those 2 levels